# How to replace old legacy hdfs connector with new fs.HadoopFileSystem?

Tags: python-3.x, hdfs, pyarrow

When i am trying replace legacy hdfs connector

```
from pyarrow import hdfs
fs = hdfs.connect()
```

,which works great with new fs connector

```
from pyarrow import fs
client = fs.HadoopFileSystem(host="default")
```

i am getting crash of python kernel.
What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if you have these three parameters set in your environment.
On your terminal check for this

```sh
echo $HADOOP_HOME
echo $JAVA_HOME
echo $ARROW_LIBHDFS_DIR
```

if not you may want to set your environment before using pyarrow. you could try this on python

```py
import os
from pyarrow import fs
os.environ['HADOOP_HOME'] = <path to hadoop binaries>
os.environ['ARROW_LIBHDFS_DIR'] = '<path to libhdfs.so>'

fs.HadoopFileSystem("hdfs://namenode:8020?user=hdfsuser")
# fs.HadoopFileSystem("namenode") should work too
```

see this - [How do i set the path of libhdfs.so for pyarrow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63173003/how-do-i-set-the-path-of-libhdfs-so-for-pyarrow/63181956#63181956)

Comment: Did you set the classpath as well?